# Limit min max in function zrangbycore in redis python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, redis, sortedset

In Python have function zrangebyscore:

```
[zrangebyscore(self, name, min, max, start=None, num=None,withscores=False, score_cast_func=float)]
```

I want to get all element in sort set have score > min and no have limit max
how do this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `min` as required min score. Specify `max` as infinity.

You may want to know how to [pass infinity to redis from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477045/how-can-i-pass-infinity-to-redis-from-python).